# Acces to SMS messages using Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, computer-science

I want to have acces to all the SMS messages available on the Android phone and store them in a SQLITE data base , but the only solution found was using BroadcastReceiver (which is not what i am looking for).

Comment: what is wrong with BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @Jason BroadcastReceiver only works when you receive the sms. My aim is to get all the messages available, not the ones received while the broadcastReceiver working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution, using ContentResolver which returns a cursor of type ICursor.

Here is the code :

```
  Android.Database.ICursor cursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null,null);
  
  StringBuilder stri = new StringBuilder("");
        while(cursor.MoveToNext())
        {
            stri.Append(cursor.GetString(0));
            //Do what ever you want 
        }
```

Note that:

```
  uri =Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://sms/inbox")
```